# Add data to ResponseText before it gets sent back.

Tags: php, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am using a JQXHR to post data to my server which adds it to a database. When I add something to the database, I want to return the ID of the article I just added to my DB. Is there any way to add something to the Responsetext before it gets sent back to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response text is the output of your php-file. That means you can do something like this in your code:

1. Insert data into db
2. Get id form db
3. `echo $id;`

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't figured that out yet. This does exactly what I want.